# Laravel 5. How to create a register using tables : users,profile and account

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-request

i'm trying to create a system of register and authentication using three tables. Users, Account and Profile.

But when attempting to use a registration form displays the following message below:[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp18S.png)

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = thiagothgb@gmail.com limit 1)

I do a relationship in the models Users like that.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Account;
use App\Model\Profile;

class Users extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    
    public function account(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Account');
    }
    
    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Profile');
    }
}
```

What I can try to for to solve this problem and extend Models when i go create a object extended.

Comment: post the registration code please.

Comment: sorry, but I can not find this. I tried use the pattern form of register. I just added one email field. I think this using the Home Controller but I deleted him and the error continuous.

You know where this register code can stay?

i try use this route 

Route::post('/register',["as" => 'auth/register','uses' => 'userController@create',] );

with this controller

Comment: <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
    
    protected function create(){
        $user = New Users();
        $user->save();
        
        $acc = New Account();
        $acc->name = $data['username'];
        $acc->email = $data['email'];
        $acc->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
        $acc->user_id = $user->id;        $acc->save();        
        return View('dashboard');    }}

Comment: Do you mean your authentication is failing?

Comment: Yes, but first I not got pass the informations for my controller. So I erased the pattern code and did do my form and it worked. Thanks